# Swift: Get UIImageView from CollectionView Cell

Tags: swift

I would like to get an UIImageView out of an UICollectionView.

I am trying to achieve this

```
@objc func carouselView(_ view:CarouselView, didSelectItemAtIndex indexPath:IndexPath) {      
    let imageView = view.collectionView(view.collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! UIImageView    
}
```

Can you help?

I am getting the error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: This is not how collection/table view work. You should have the imageViews as part of your model and better only the image. This data is surely available when you create your cells. The error comes from that a collectionView is not an UIImageView

Comment: Looks like you're trying to retrieve an image after it's been selected. You should rely on the model actually. Since you get the `indexPath` out of a tap on the collectionView, you can get the corresponding Image that's being displayed there via the model (e.g. the array of images that allowed you to build the collection in the first place). From there, you create *another* UIImageView (programatically) with the same UIImage

Answer (score 0):

I understand you would like to modify your `UIImageView` or whatever.. THIS is unacceptable approach because the right way is relying on Model since your collection view has items corresponding to indexPath where you can access your array model at index.

So, what you should do is access your array and update it then reload at index or reload all.

Comment: P.S. You have the ability to reload specific row / item